# PDO fails on selecting large number of records

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to fetch all rows of a MySQL table. Here is the code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table";
$connection = new 
PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8','user', 'password');
$statement =$connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The `my_table` table has 145 columns with 11000 records. 
When I run the code it fails to fetch all records. But when I change $sql to `SELECT ID FROM my_table` or `SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 4000` it runs successfully.

Is there any limitation for PDO to fetch data or am I misusing it?

**SLUTION**

After checking Apache error log I saw this error: `apache weAllowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted`. AS @Marcin Orlowski said in comments it is a memory issue. So I should select columns that are needed and use `where` clause to filter my records.

Comment: Yep - memory. Check your error log.

Comment: Aside from your memory problems you are most likely fetching here, I really doubt you need all 11000 rows fetched. This usually indicates you should stop and sit down to rethink what you really doing and what for.

Comment: My apologies. I didn't even consider checking error log. Such a dumb question. I spent a day on googling.

Comment: @Martin Orlowski you are right. I don't need all the data. I was testing a piece of code then I came across this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should add foreach option to fetch it properly.. 
just echo the row column as below to display the columns whatever there.

```
<?php
$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8','user', 'password');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `my_table`";
$statement =$connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$result1 = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//Re written by Ajmal PraveeN
foreach($result1 as $result){
echo $result['column'];
echo $result['column2'];
}
?>
```

Comment: this line fails. `$result1 = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` . So it is not possible to loop through rows.